# What do these cocoonJS terms of use mean

Tags: licensing, legal

I was looking at the [terms of use](https://cloud.ludei.com/terms/) for CocoonJS and noticed this section

> License Grant. By uploading User Content via the Services, you expressly grant, and you represent and warrant that you have a right to grant, and do so grant, to Ludei, a royalty-free, non-exclusive, worldwide license to use, reproduce, modify, publish, list information regarding, edit, translate, and make derivative works of all such User Content and your name, voice, and/or likeness as contained in your User Content, if applicable, in whole or in part, and in any form, media or technology, whether now known or hereafter developed, solely for use in connection with the Services.

I am not too clear on the legal jargon, but to me this sounds like I'm basically giving someone unrestricted access to any intellectual property that I have submitted to their servers, and the ability to use my identity in any form as they wish.

Can someone clarify what the excerpt means?

Comment: IANAL but this the last sentence seems to limit what can be done with your IP `solely for use in connection with the Services`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because legal advice is off topic on Programmers. See: [When is a software licensing question on topic?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7265/88986)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With much of the cloud and hosting services for various things (photographs, code, t-shirt designs, blogs), it is necessary to do things with that data to be able to do what you want the service to do.

Take for example an image that you've uploaded as a png for the icon for the page.   That license allows them to convert it to a jpeg. Or if they need to make a thumbnail for the gallery, that is a transformation of the image. If you upload the instructions for a game in English, they have the ability to translate them into French.  If you upload the associated files one at a time, they have the license to repackage them into a single deployable.  And in all cases, they have the permission to host the information that you've put up there to be hosted.

Without this license, they would not be able to legally host any files, resize the images, package up things into the proper executable format, and be on the hook for royalties.

This license is largely a very standard "if you upload something for other people to download (play online or whatnot) we have permission to host it without being charged a royalty and make associated tweaks necessary for hosting it on our site."